# Set background to image control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, background

I've an Image Control in a WPF Form. When there's no image loaded. I want to make it dark gray but all of the controls have the Background exept the Image control.

Does anybody knows **how** can I **set a background to the image control in the XAML?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can just surround your image with border:

```
<Border Height="300" Width="300" Background="Gray">
    <Image Stretch="Fill" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it: use a PNG file as a background

```
<Image Source="Background.png" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: not the best way since your background is an additional resource.